# IndexError: list index out of range, but index exists

Tags: python

I've written the following code:

```
def get_sublist(lst, starter, end):
res = []
start = False
temp = []

for item in lst:
    if item == starter:
        start = True
        temp.append(item)

    elif item == end:
        start = False
        temp.append(item)
        res.append(temp)
        temp = []

    elif start:
        temp.append(item)
    else:
        pass

print(res)
print(res[0])
return list(zip(res[0], res[0][1:]))
```

(assume the indentation is correct)

Basically, it slices a list based on a starter and ending element. In my example, these elements are tuples.

The results of the two print statements are:

```
[[(0.25, 0.5), (0.9, 0.35), (0.9, 0.35), (0.2, 0.5)]]
[(0.25, 0.5), (0.9, 0.35), (0.9, 0.35), (0.2, 0.5)]
```

Yet the traceback specifically points to `print(res[0])` as the indexing error. however, it even prints, and I can visually verify that yes there is a 0th element in the list. So why is it giving such an error?

Edit: based on comment, this is how I am calling function:

```
o1, o2, d1, d2 = [(0.25, 0.5), (0.9, 0.35), (0.2, 0.5), (0.9, 0.35)]
lst = [(0.05, 0.3), (0.25, 0.5), (0.9, 0.35), (0.9, 0.35), (0.2, 0.5)]

o2d2 = get_sublist(lst, o2, d2)
```

Further edit: upon restarting the terminal, I no longer see the two print statements previously mentioned. only see [] printed now.

Comment: What do you really mean from your question? I don't get it how can it print when it even meets an error.

Comment: @DhanaD. Yes, that is what confuses me as well. It meets an error on that specific line, yet it still prints out. Also, it shouldn't even be meeting the error, because as the print statements show, there does exist a 0th element in the list.

Comment: Please include how you're calling the function.

Comment: @luther updated

Comment: Looks like `res` is empty, because `o2` and `d2` indicate elements that are right next to each other in `lst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unnecessarily making things complicated for simple problem - *You are not handling some of the cases when both values are equal, when duplicates exist in lst etc.,*.

Since you need a slice of `lst` between `starter` and `end`, you can do this:

- Iterate over the `lst` and see if `starter` exists. If yes, store its index in a variable `start_idx` and `break` from loop. *The default values of `start_idx` and `end_idx` are `None`*
- Now Iterate in reverse way and see if `end` exists. If yes, store that index in `end_idx`.
- If `start_idx` and `end_idx` are not `None`, Return the slice of the `lst` - `lst[start_idx: end_idx+1]`. Else return `Not Found`.

```
def get_sublist(lst, starter, end):
    start_idx, end_idx = None, None
    for i,v in enumerate(lst):
        if v == starter:
            start_idx = i
            break

    for i in range(len(lst)-1,-1,-1):
        if lst[i] == end:
            end_idx = i
            break

    if start_idx is not None and end_idx is not None:
        return lst[start_idx:end_idx+1]
    return "Not Found"
        
     
o1, o2, d1, d2 = [(0.25, 0.5), (0.9, 0.35), (0.2, 0.5), (0.9, 0.35)]
lst = [(0.05, 0.3), (0.25, 0.5), (0.9, 0.35), (0.9, 0.35), (0.2, 0.5)]

print(get_sublist(lst, o1, d2))
print(get_sublist(lst, d2, d1))
print(get_sublist(lst, (0.6, 0.3), d2))
```

```
[(0.25, 0.5), (0.9, 0.35), (0.9, 0.35)]
[(0.9, 0.35), (0.9, 0.35), (0.2, 0.5)]
Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

To account for the case where the `starter` and `end` parameters have equal value, you have to switch the logic to check whether a sublist has started first so that it knows to end instead of starting a second sublist and ending neither.

See below:

```py
if start:
    if item == end:
        start = False
        temp.append(item)
        res.append(temp)
        temp = []
    else:
        temp.append(item)
else:
    if item == starter:
        start = True
        temp.append(item)
    else:
        pass
```

**That said**, this does not handle if no sublists are found with the given conditions, or if a starter is found and no end, an end with no starter, etc.